# Call dictionary from variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dictionary_a = {
    "name": "a"
}
```

and a variable:

```
dictionary_selection = "dictionary_a"
```

Is there a way to get elements from the dictionary determined by the variable?

E.g.

Is there some way to get a script like this to work?

```
print(dictionary_selection["name"])
```

Not sure if this is possible or if the title is correct

Comment: The normal way to select something by name in Python is a dictionary.  So you'd have something like `all_dicts = {'dictionary_a': {...}, ...}`, and use `all_dicts[dictionary_selection]["name"]` to retrieve an item from a specified dictionary.

Comment: variable variables dupe  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/674039

Answer (score 1):

You may have a try on globals() and locals() functions.

```
>>> dictionary_a = {"name":"a"}
>>> dictionary_selection = "dictionary_a"
>>> globals().get(dictionary_selection)["name"]
'a'
# locals() use like globals()
```

But the better way may be:

```
data = {}
data["dictionary_a"] = {"name":"a"}
dictionary_selection = "dictionary_a"
data.get(dictionary_selection)["name"]
# this way can control the data by yourself with out the constraint of namespaces
```

emmm,hope can help you .

Answer (score -1):

It can be done like this.

```
dictionary_a = {"name": "a"}
dictionary_selection = "dictionary_a"
key="name"
index=eval(dictionary_selection+"["+"'"+key+"'"+"]")
print(index)
```

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a dictionary d

```py
d={'apple': 'fruit', 'onion':'vegetable'}
```

Trying to do the following will give you an error:

```py
dict_name='d'
print(d['apple'])
```

This is because `dict_name` stores a `string` with value `d`. Even though `d` is the name of a variable, python does not know to evaluate it as such and you will get an error like

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

You could evaluate the string by doing this:

```
eval(dict_name)['apple']
```

This will evaluate the variable, see that it is a dictionary, and give you the output `apple`.

However, this is not a good way to do it. You would be better off using another dictionary or list to keep track of all your dictionaries.

with list:

```py
dict_list=[d, d1, ...]
print(dict_list[0]['apple'])
```

with dictionary:

```
all_dicts{'d':d}
print(all_dicts['d']['apple'])
```

Comment: to people downvoting this answer, may I know why? what can i do to improve it?